# Import cv2 error, shared object dependencies not found

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, opencv3.0, ldd

The OpenCV Forum tells me my question is more related to Linux, not OpenCV, therefore I asked here.

I have `import cv2` error, see the description below:

The cv2.so is under the paths:

```sh
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2.so
```

I have no idea why I have `cv2.so` under each python version, I build `opencv` with `python3`

I added to the `~/.bashrc` file:

```sh
    export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

But, when I run in `python3`:

```py
import cv2
```

It gives me this message:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):`
> `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
> `ImportError: libopencv_hdf.so.3.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How could I solve this? Thank you.

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
OpenCV 3.4.0 build with `contrib`, `python3`, `python3-numpy`.
```

Code when build OpenCV3.4.0

*PS*: I have installed OpenCV3 twice. If you need my first-time CMake command, please follow the [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/183004/install-opencv3-with-python3python3-numpy/)

I found a problem by using `ldd` to check shared dependencies:

```sh
    ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2.so

    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffacda1000)
    libopencv_hdf.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_reg.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_surface_matching.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_xphoto.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_freetype.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_fuzzy.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_img_hash.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_bioinspired.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_saliency.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_ccalib.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_rgbd.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_structured_light.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_aruco.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_bgsegm.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_face.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_optflow.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_stitching.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_objdetect.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_photo.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_tracking.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_plot.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_text.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_dnn.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_ximgproc.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_ml.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_shape.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_video.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_features2d.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_flann.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_highgui.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_videoio.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 => not found
    libopencv_core.so.3.4 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff9d06b2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff9d03a9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff9d0193000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff9cfdc9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff9d10cd000)
```

Could anyone give very detailed instructions to do solve this?

*Update:*

Add ...gitclone.../opencv/build/lib to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and import cv2, it gived this:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):`
> `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
> `ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN2cv3dnn19experimental_dnn_v35LayerE`

Comment: The problem is that by the second time I installed OpenCV, it is actually opencv2 is installed, not opencv3. Solution: check whether you have all dependencies are installed, reinstall OpenCV3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your OpenCV libraries are not linked to the right locations.
You can try to do:

```sh
ldconfig -v
```

If this doesn't help, you need to reinstall OpenCV following the instructions precisely.